# icons shown in one row instead of column

Tags: html, css

I saw that this question already exists, but I cant apply those answers to my case, it didnt work for me. I am trying to display this icons in one row, one next to each other, but they always finish in column. How can I change it please ? I do not want to use bootstrap, nor html5, only html.

```html
<div class="row" style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">
  <div class="status-icons-text-color temperature-data-icons">
    <div align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="first temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/first_temp_icon_outline_white.png" style="max-width:20px;">
      <div id="first_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold;font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</div>
    </div>
    <div align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="second temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/second_temp_icon_white.png" style="max-height:20px;">
      <div id="second_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</div>
    </div>
    <div align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Third temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/third_temp_white.png" style="max-height:20px;">
      <div id="third_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about putting them all in one row in a table?

Comment: how ? they are in one div, I dont know which changes to apply to have them in a row

Comment: I responded with an answer (see below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Div tags are block level, which means they will automatically be as wide as their container.  This tends to make them stack up vertically if you have several in a row.

I have applied a `float: left;` to your 3rd level nested div, which makes them both inline and floated left.  Inline means they are only as big as their contents, and floated left makes them stack up next to one another starting on the left.

I also applied a second style to your innermost divs - to make them inline.

```css
div > div.status-icons-text-color.temperature-data-icons > div {
  float: left;
}
div > div.status-icons-text-color.temperature-data-icons > div > div{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">
  <div class="status-icons-text-color temperature-data-icons">
    <div align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="first temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/first_temp_icon_outline_white.png" style="max-width:20px;">
      <div id="first_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold;font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</div>
    </div>
    <div align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="second temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/second_temp_icon_white.png" style="max-height:20px;">
      <div id="second_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</div>
    </div>
    <div align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Third temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/third_temp_white.png" style="max-height:20px;">
      <div id="third_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you'd prefer this work without the additional CSS, you could always swap the divs for spans.

```html
<span class="row" style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">
  <span class="status-icons-text-color temperature-data-icons">
    <span align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="first temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/first_temp_icon_outline_white.png" style="max-width:20px;">
      <span id="first_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold;font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</span>
    </span>
    <span align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="second temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/second_temp_icon_white.png" style="max-height:20px;">
      <span id="second_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</span>
    </span>
    <span align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Third temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/third_temp_white.png" style="max-height:20px;">
      <span id="third_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: amazing thank You. can You shortly explain me how You wrote this class i never wrote div inside a css class, how You use it?

Comment: Here's a link to get you started:  http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/introduction-css-selectors/

Comment: If you want more or different resources, search for the term `CSS selectors`.  That's the term for how you target HTML with CSS.

Comment: just to add one more question. What would be in situation that is also one big div class row, and inside are 3 divs, but inside divs are a href and some image. what should I take then for a css class, to have them in one row ?

Comment: a ok, I used a:link and it works, only there is no space between icons ?

Comment: Try applying a margin.  That's a common way to insert space between elements.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (see comment)

```html
<div class="row" style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">
  <div class="status-icons-text-color temperature-data-icons">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="first temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/first_temp_icon_outline_white.png" style="max-width:20px;">
      <div id="first_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold;font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</div>
    </div></td>
    <td><div align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="second temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/second_temp_icon_white.png" style="max-height:20px;">
      <div id="second_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</div>
    </div></td>
    <td><div align=c enter data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Third temperature">
      <img src="images/icons/third_temp_white.png" style="max-height:20px;">
      <div id="third_temp" style="padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">-- °C</div>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might argue that this is tabular data, but I still avoid using tables for layout whenever I can.